# React variable don't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I've been trying to calculate the total travel time between several places using the Google Maps API. But when trying to access the variable `total_duration` with the above information does not show me anything on the console.

```
const responses = [];
    let total_duration = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < origins.length ; i++){
      const matrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      matrix.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: origins[i],
        destinations: destinations[i],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      }, 
      function(response, status){
        responses.push(response);
      });
    }
    console.log(responses);
    for(let i = 0 ; i < responses.length ; i++){
      total_duration += responses[i].rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
      console.log(responses[i])
    }
    console.log(total_duration);
```

The first console log shows me all the results for every couple of places.

```
[
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "elements": [
          {
            "distance": {
              "text": "1.2 km",
              "value": 1161
            },
            "duration": {
              "text": "3 mins",
              "value": 169
            },
            "status": "OK"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "originAddresses": [
      "3670 SW 3rd St, Miami, FL 33135, USA"
    ],
    "destinationAddresses": [
      "3911 SW 2nd Terrace, Coral Gables, FL 33134, USA"
    ]
  },
  {
    "rows": [
      {
        "elements": [
          {
            "distance": {
              "text": "1.5 km",
              "value": 1473
            },
            "duration": {
              "text": "4 mins",
              "value": 226
            },
            "status": "OK"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "originAddresses": [
      "3911 SW 2nd Terrace, Coral Gables, FL 33134, USA"
    ],
    "destinationAddresses": [
      "4490 SW 5th Terrace, Coral Gables, FL 33134, USA"
    ]
  }
]
```

But the other console logs do not show me the info I need. Can you help me with this error? Thank you in advance.

Now, when I try to update `state` in `getTimes` function, my state don't update. Time is always `0`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class HomePage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: 0,
      places: [
        {latitude: some_data, longitude: some_data},
        {latitude: some_data, longitude: some_data}
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){}

  getTimes = () => {
    const origins = [], destinations = [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < this.state.places.length - 1 ; i++){
      origins.push([new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.places[i].latitude, 
        this.state.places[i].longitude)]);
      destinations.push([new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.places[i + 1].latitude, 
        this.state.places[i + 1].longitude)]);  
    }
    let total_duration = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < origins.length ; i++){
      const matrix = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      matrix.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: origins[i],
        destinations: destinations[i],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      }, 
      (response, status) => {
        total_duration += response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
        console.log(total_duration);
        this.setState({time: total_duration});
      });
    }
    console.log(this.state.time);    
  }

  render() {
    const {time} = this.state;
    return (
      <h1>{time}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please try  console.log(total_duration); inside for loop

Comment: I still do not show anything, nor undefined nor a blank line or zero.

Comment: `matrix.getDistanceMatrix` doesn't return a Promise, so `await` on that does not actually wait for the callback to complete - see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/distance-matrix)

Comment: It still don's show me nothing. I've edited my question.

Comment: console.log(responses[i]) what shows this

Comment: It shows nothing inside the for. If I put it out of the for: `console.log (responses [0])` for example, it shows me undefined.

Comment: removing `await` doesn't fix the issue - it's still an asynchronous callback that pushes to `responses` that you are not dealing with

Comment: `all the results for every couple of places` - so, it's not all the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.setState(state => {
  const newTime = state.time + total_duration
  return { count: newTime }
}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.time);  
})
```

Comment: can you try this, if it works use state variable for total_duration with origins.length

Comment: Thank you very much, it shows me the times but when I do console log out of the for it does not show me anything. I set it to keep `total_duration` in the state but it tells me that `this.setState` is undefined.

Comment: it is react thing, what is the function you called, did you bind it in constructor or use arrow function

Comment: I've tested with an arrow function but then the status is not updated

Comment: are you able to put the whole js file ( component )

Comment: this.setState({
    time: total_duration 
},() => {
    console.log(this.state.time);
});

Comment: this.setState(
       (prevState,props)=>{
           return {time:prevState.time+total_duration};
        }
    );

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll update your answer with my code.